# linux key aliases

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Ubuntu, and I would like to make some key aliases - such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> can be alias to <kbd>Down</kbd> key, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to <kbd>U</kbd> and so on. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are under X11, you'd create a custom keyboard layout that suits your needs.
Have a look to this [tutorial](http://hektor.umcs.lublin.pl/~mikosmul/computing/articles/custom-keyboard-layouts-xkb.html) by Michał Kosmulski.